# Adding double quotes to a string in Dataweave

Tags: dataweave, mule4

I'm trying to add double quotes to my message to format it a certain way but i cant seem to figure out how. Here is my input:

```
{
  "Id": "0065e00000JyZi5AAG",
  "Description": "desc104"
}
```

And this is my intended output:

```
{
  ":Id": "{"S": payload.Id}",
  ":Description": "{"S": payload.Description}"
}
```

I was able to figure out most of the mapping (expect the double quote issue). Here is my working code:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var keysArray = namesOf(payload)
var ss = "S"
---

payload mapObject ((value, key, index) -> 
{
  (":" ++ keysArray[(index)]): ("{" ++ "S"  ++ ": " ++ "payload." ++ (key) ++"}")
})
```

Comment: That would not be a valid string representation in the output. You would need to escape the "" around S or surround the whole value with '' instead of "".

Comment: As @SalimKhan said, It is not valid JSON to have unescaped quotes inside a string.

Answer (score 1):

You can not have quotes that are not escaped inside a JSON string, because quotes are the string delimiters. That is just not valid JSON and DataWeave doesn't write invalid outputs.

I'm assuming your use case is to have a JSON object as a value inside a string. For that to work you need to escape the quotes and other special characters that JSON uses. Fortunately DataWeave does that automatically when writing JSON. Using the write() function you can write a DataWeave object to JSON as a string that will be corrected escaped.

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload mapObject ((value, key, index) -> 
{
    (":" ++ key as String): write({ S : payload[key]}, "application/json", {indent:false})
})
```

Output:

```json
{
  ":Id": "{\"S\": \"0065e00000JyZi5AAG\"}",
  ":Description": "{\"S\": \"desc104\"}"
}
```

If you want to use the parse the strings as JSON you need whatever application that uses the input to be able to parse it. In DataWeave is easy with the read() function, the opposite function to write().

Example:

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
read(payload.":Id", "application/json")
```

Output:

```json
{
  "S": "0065e00000JyZi5AAG"
}
```